# Getting a double output of last input after a validation check in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, validation, pycharm

I'm learning input validation in a while loop. If i enter 1, 2, 3, x, -1 as my inputs it prints 1, 2, 3, 3. Can someone explain why it outputs the 3 twice. Is my try statement incorrect or in the wrong spot?

```
def input_validation_while_loop():

    list = []

    guess_num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop."))

    # sentinel_value = -1
    while guess_num != -1:
        try:
            if 1 <= guess_num <= 100:
                list.append(guess_num)
            guess_num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop."))
        except ValueError:
            print("That was not a number. Try again.")

    else:
        for x in list:
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `while` loop and getting rid of the redundant input statement:

```
def input_validation_while_loop():    
    list = []          
    # sentinel_value = -1
    while True:
        try:
            guess_num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop."))
            if 1 <= guess_num <= 100:
                list.append(guess_num)
            elif guess_num == -1:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("That was not a number. Try again.")

    for x in list:
        print(x)
input_validation_while_loop()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop.1                                                                                                                       
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop.2                                                                                                                       
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop.3                                                                                                                       
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop.x                                                                                                                       
That was not a number. Try again.                                                                                                                                            
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter -1 to stop.-1                                                                                                                      
1                                                                                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                                                            
3
```